# Kaplan-Meier / NPMLE / semi-parametric ph survival curve troubleshooting

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, interval-censoring

I've got my survival curves looking like this:

NPMLE using icenReg
[image]

semi_parametric using icenReg

[image]

and cox PH, where right side of interval is used as time of event

[image]

Why do the survival curves estimated by icenReg have that strange vertical line at the end? How should I interpret it and is this something I should worry about?

My initial thought would be that there is a single patient who had an event at a time with right interval closing at around 1400, while the last censored patient got censored before that time... but the normal cox ph doesn't have that line. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic survival model assumes that all individuals eventually experience the event.* When the last observation is right-censored, the question is how to estimate survival beyond that time, as described in the Section 4.2 Practical Notes of [Klein and Moeschberger](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953991). There are two extreme possibilities: Efron's "assuming that the survivor with the largest time on study would have died immediately after the survivor’s censoring time," and Gill's "assuming this individual would die at $\infty$." Those are respectively negatively and positively biased estimates of late-time survival. Klein and Moeschberger discuss intermediate possibilities, but those aren't typical choices for display.

Evidently the [`icenReg` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icenReg) software makes the Efron assumption in representing that drop to 0 survival. The way that baseline survival is typically estimated in a Cox model, however, if the last observation is right-censored then the survival curve never drops below the survival estimated at the last event time, the Gill assumption. In a Cox model you will get a drop to 0 survival if the last observation time is for an event.

---

*The high survival fraction at late times suggests that your data might better be represented by a "cure model" that allows some individuals never to experience the event.

Comment: Thanks EdM! do you know if there's a way to make icenReg assume the "cure model" instead?

Comment: @Wojty I'm not that intimately familiar with `icenReg`. If these plots are from the data on diabetic retinopathy described in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/598070/28500), I'm not convinced that you should be worrying so much about the interval-censoring aspect. From a patient's perspective, I'd rather have a bias toward earlier screening, which you would get by assigning event times to the last event-free observation before a later event observation. Sometimes an unbiased estimate, like you ideally get with proper handling of interval censoring, isn't the best choice.